# Characterization of p-adic analytic functions

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Is there a characterization of which p-adic functions, $f(x)$, can be expressed as a power series in $x$? I'm thinking something akin to "all infinitely differentiable functions can be expressed as a convergent power series" (I’m not sure if this is true).

Comment: Non-constant locally constant functions are smooth but not expressible as a single power series, they are locally analytic but not globally.

Comment: A classic source for this would be [W. Schikhof's *Ultrametric Calculus*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/ultrametric-calculus/FD8E1172062BF97D41430B559C895CCC). Note that e.g. the function $\sum a_n p^n \mapsto \sum a_np^{2n}$ has derivative $0$, so is very infinitely differentiable and very *not* locally analytic (Example 26.4) -- For (locally) analytic functions in general, look at section 25, for their Mahler coefficients, Thm 54.4. -- Also note that Schikhof champions a concept of $C^n$ functions which is stronger than usual. Still, not all $C^\infty$ functions are locally analytic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're clearly interested in an answer more substantial than "a function is analytic if and only if it is analytic".

That infinite differentiability should imply (local) analyticity is false over $\mathbf R$, so it's not surprising this shouldn't work over $\mathbf Q_p$ as well. That it works over $\mathbf C$ is kind of a miracle.

Let's take a cue from classical Fourier series on $\mathbf R$, where the rate of decay of the Fourier coefficients is related to the amount of smoothness of the function (I'm not saying there is an equivalence, but there's definitely a relationship). We look around for series expansions of $p$-adic functions, and the Mahler expansion for continuous functions turns out to be nice in this respect. The continuous functions $f : \mathbf Z_p \to \mathbf Q_p$ are precisely those that admit a series representation $f(x) = \sum a_n\binom{x}{n}$ for all $x$ in $\mathbf Z_p$ where $|a_n|_p \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. That series is the Mahler expansion of $f$. It turns out that $f$ is $p$-adic analytic, meaning it is expressible as a single power series $\sum_{n \geq 0} c_nx^n$ on all of $\mathbf Z_p$, if and only if its Mahler coefficients $a_n$ satisfy the relation $|a_n/n!|_p \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
For a proof, see Theorem 4.4 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/mahlerexpansions.pdf).

Comment: Just adding that according to Schikhof (see comment at OP), $f$ is $C^1$ ("strictly differentiable", which in the $p$-adic world is a stronger concept than the usual $C^1$) if and only if $$ (\ast) \lim_{n \to \infty} \lvert a_n \rvert_p \cdot n =0,$$ and $C^\infty$ if and only if for all $k \in \mathbb N$, $$ (**) \lim_{n \to \infty} \lvert a_n \rvert_p \cdot n^k =0.$$ It is not too hard to come up with a sequence $a_n$ which satisfies $(**)$ but not your $\lim_{n\to \infty} \lvert a_n/n!\rvert_p=0$, which gives a $C^\infty$ function that is not analytic.

Comment: What about *locally* analytic functions though? I imagine by compactness of $\mathbb Z_p$, we just have to exclude any given finite radius, and I strongly suspect there is a likewise criterion on how fast the Mahler coefficients $a_n$ go to $0$, which would determine a function to be, say, analytic on the ball around $0$ with radius $p^{-k}$ (as opposed to all of $\mathbb Z_p$). Schikhof refers to Y. Amice, *Interpolation $p$-adique*, Bull. Soc. Math. France 92 (1964), pp. 117-180 for that.

Comment: Ah. Here is the article: http://www.numdam.org/item/10.24033/bsmf.1606.pdf, and the results, just a bit cumbersome to write down, are in corollaire 2 and 3, p. 162-163.

Comment: The condition on Mahler coefficients $\{a_n\}$ for local analyticity of a continuous function $f \colon \mathbf Z_p \to \mathbf Q_p$ is $\varliminf {\rm ord}_p(a_n)/n > 0$ in the real numbers.

Comment: And for an integer $h \geq 0$, $f$ is analytic on all the cosets of $p^h\mathbf Z_p$ ("analytic of order $h$") if and only if $|a_n/\lfloor{n/p^h\rfloor}!|_p \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Taking $h=0$, this turns into the analyticity-on-$\mathbf Z_p$ criterion $|a_n/n!|_p \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ that I wrote in my answer above.